# instantiating a class without assigning to a variable

Tags: php

I have a need to call a class which will perform actions but which I know I will not be calling the methods of.  This is a PHP application.  Does anyone ever just do the following:

```
require('class.Monkeys.php');
new Monkeys(); //note I didn't assign it to a variable
```

Comment: You *can* do that. I don't quite understand why you should want to, however.

Comment: Maybe that's the main framework and everything else happens inside this class.

Comment: @RaphaelMüller in that scenario I'd favour a `run()` method - `(new Monkeys())->run()`. Otherwise it's not immediately obvious to a reader that something meaningful happens when the class is instantiated.

Comment: usually, I agree you instantiate a class to use it, but we have a system that requires all tables to be referenced inside a class.  So, before adding a table join to a query, I need to call this class (which inspects it for field updates etc.).  I know it will not be used in this script's context.

Comment: @bcmcfc I completely agree, that's the way to go.

Comment: Maybe you should think about a static method `Monkeys::update()` then.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, that's perfectly valid. However, it is arguably bad form, because the golden rule is that:

> Constructors should not do actual work.

A constructor should set up an object so that it is valid and in a "ready state". The constructor should not start to perform work on its own. As such, this would be saner:

```
$monkeys = new Monkeys;
$monkeys->goWild();
```

Or, if you prefer and are running a sufficiently advanced PHP version:

```
(new Monkeys)->goWild();
```

Comment: Would suggesting a static class setup provide extra knowledge of such a case? Then OP would be able to call methods without resorting back to a variable, rather the class name

Comment: I don't really see the big advantage. A static class method that would essentially do the above two (one) line(s) of code seem pretty superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

Well let just say that we have a classname called **Monkeys**.

File `class.Monkeys.php`

```
class Monkeys {

   function __construct()
   {
       $this->doSomething()
   }

   public function doSomething(){
       echo "new Monkeys()->doSomething() was called";
   }

   public function anotherMethod(){
       echo "new Monkeys()->anotherMethod() was called";
   }
}
```

Now you can instantiate the class on runtime without saving it into a variable.

```
require('class.Monkeys.php');
// you can just instantiate it and the constructur will be called automatically 
(new Monkeys());

// or you can instantiate it and call other methods
(new Monkeys())->anotherMethod();
```

I'm not sure if the garbage collector will delete the instantiated classes or not, but i assume since those classes are not saved into a variable this would not be saved somewhere in the memory and that would be perfect.