# Storing new class in a variable and then do var_dump() works, but when I directly try to var_dump() it without storing it throws an error?

Tags: php, oop

I am learning oops concept in PHP and trying to poke around code and got stuck in this question.

Whole code

```
<?php

class Person
{
private $name;
private $email;

public function __construct($name, $email)
{
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->email = $email;
    echo __CLASS__." Created <br>";
}

}

class Customers extends Person
{
private $balance;

public function __construct($name, $email, $balance)
{
    $this->balance = $balance;
    parent::__construct($name, $email, $balance);
    echo 'A new '.__CLASS__." Has Been Created <br>";

}

public function getBalance()
{
    return $this->balance.'<br>';
}
}
$customer1 = new Customers('john Don', 'jorand@khat.desi', 300);
die(var_dump($customer1->getBalance()));
```

I got question here

Why does this executes

```
$customer1 = new Customers('john Don', 'jorand@khat.com', 300);
die(var_dump($customer1->getBalance()));
```

And this throws an error

```
die(var_dump(new Customers('john Don', 'jorand@khat.com', 300)->getBalance()));
```

Comment: Hope this will help : [instantiating a class without assigning to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24654131/instantiating-a-class-without-assigning-to-a-variable). Example  :https://3v4l.org/K3X3B

Comment: Oh Thanks, that helped very much and has solved my doubt. I understand that it can be done by just adding brackets around the instantiation, but it is not a good practice so I need to avoid it in general. Thanks again.